# Retrieving a Store Field from Inside a Relationship Field

Tags: expresso-store, relationships

Using EE 2.10.1 and Store v2.4.0
I need to get the value of a Store field out from a related entry.
My code is currently this (abbreviated to make it easier to read):

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1"}   <!-- main product tag -->
  {exp:store:product_form}                           <!-- starts the form allowing multi add to cart submit -->
    {related_item}                                   <!-- opens tag pair for relationship field and loops related items -->
      {exp:store:product entry_id="{related_item:entry_id}" disable_form="yes"} <!-- output individual related item-->
        <p>{related_item:title} - {price}</p>        <!-- Really really want Store field access here! -->
      {exp:store:product}
    {/related_item}
  {/exp:store:product_form}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

However I've tried any number of ways to get the price (or any other Store value) to show without any luck e.g.

```
{price}
{related_item:price}
{related_item:regular_price}
{related_item:store_field_name:price}
```

but so far no joy with anything.
Is this even possible?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried putting the store item in an embed?

Sample template code

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="products" limit="1"}
  {related_item}
    {embed="_embed-template" the_id="{related_item:entry_id}"}
  {/related_item}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Then in the embed:

```
{exp:store:product entry_id="{embed:the_id}" disable_form="yes"}
  {title} - {price}
{/exp:store:product}
```

That should work...

Comment: Not entirely sure why but this seems to make things worse!
This approach now isn't parsing the related field values i.e. {related_item:title}.
It *does* send the entry_id through to the embed but the contents of the embed don't seem to be being parsed.
Do I need to consider inward parsing somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I am a little ashamed...
I have found the answer and it was in my code all along... I enabled template debugging and it showed me that I hadn't closed the {exp:store:product} tag correctly (missed the slash)
@bluedreamer - your code was spot on and also simplified the template a little too